# How to Split the nodevalues on php dom element

Tags: php, dom

i scrape the website, i am getting result of below in single element, i want to split the one by one element.

code:

```
$dom1 = new DomDocument();
@ $dom1->loadHTML($res1);
$jobview=$dom1->getElementById('test');
foreach($jobview->getElementsByTagName('div') as $divlist){
    echo $test=$divlist->nodeValue; 
}
```

input:-

```
<strong>Testcontent</strong> <br><br> "Test" <br></br>
```

Current output:-

```
Testcontent Test
```

expecting output:-

```
array[0]=>Testcontent [1]=>Test
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the input and the output you are getting/expect to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the text parts is a part of the `<div>` tag, so this code just assumes that you want the text from each direct child not and adds it to an array in the loop using `[]`...

```
$output = [];
foreach($jobview->getElementsByTagName('div') as $divlist){
    foreach ( $divlist->childNodes as $node )   {
        if ( trim($node->textContent) ) {
            $output[] = $node->textContent;
        }
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: No nigel , i am getting output of Array([0] => Testcontent Test) using above code

Comment: $divlist->nodeValue is an single array, so i need inside the data as split it as [0] as testcontent and [1] as test

Comment: I've updated to split out the child nodes into the parts.